# friendship getting inherited ?? strange

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend

As it is said - "**friends are not inherited**" .
it means that

```
class c
 {public:
 friend void i_am_friend();
 };

class d:public c
{public:
 //
};
```

here  **void i_am_friend()** is not inherited in class d .In more technical terms(i think this way.)

Object of class d will not have memory allocated for **void i_am_friend()** as it is friend of base class .
Now consider question no. 14.3 at this page  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/friends.html

```
class Base {
 public:
   friend void f(Base& b);
   ...
 protected:
   virtual void do_f();
   ...
 };

 inline void f(Base& b)
 {
   b.do_f();
 }

 class Derived : public Base {
 public:
   ...
 protected:
   virtual void do_f();  // "Override" the behavior of f(Base& b)
   ...
 };

 void userCode(Base& b)
 {
   f(b);
 }
```

How can this code be correct?? because

> class derived d;// d will not have friend function
>       class base *b=&d; //as a result b also don't have member function

So call to f(b) should be error here.

**So what is correct to say :-

friendship isn't inherited

or friendship is inherited but  can't be used in derived class**

Answer (score 2):

> friendship isn't inherited

This is true, even in your example. The call to f(b) should NOT be an error there, because the `Derived` object is converted into `Base&` type.

The function `f` can access only the private and protected parts of the `Base` class, but only public parts of the `Derived` class.